# Read an include file using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-2.0

I want your opinion on what should be my approach to solve this problem. I have a file by the name nav.inc which contains text like for example:

```
<li class="closed"><a title="x" href="x.html">x</a></li>
<li class="closed"><a title="y" href="y.html">y</a></li>
<li class="closed"><a title="z" href="a.html">z</a></li>
```

I want to parse this file in xsl so that I can compare each value inside `a` tag with a variable. The condition is that the extension needs to be `.inc`, which also means it's not going to be a valid XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
The condition is that the extension needs to be .inc, which also means it's not going to be a valid XML
```

**The extension in the file name doesn't mean that the contents cannot be a well-formed XML document.**

As the provided example is a completely well-formed XML fragment, you need to arrange that this fragment is wrapped into a single top element.

**Then just use the `document()` function:**

```
$myVar = document('fileName.inc')/*/li[@class = 'closed']/a
```

The evaluation of this XPath (1.0) expression produces `true()` if the string value of `$myVar` is equal to the string value of of an `a` element that is a child of a `li` element whose `class` attribute has string value `"closed"` and that is a child of the top element of the XML document contained in the file `fileName.inc`.

---

**If it really cannot be aranged that the file contains a well-formed XML document**, use [`unparsed-text()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#function-unparsed-text) and [`xsl:analyze-string`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#analyze-string).

**Here is a complete transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vText" select=
      "unparsed-text('file:///c:/temp/delete/fileName.inc')"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:analyze-string select="$vText" regex="&gt;([^&lt;]*)&lt;/a&gt;" flags="m">
       <xsl:matching-substring>
         <value><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/></value>
       </xsl:matching-substring>
     </xsl:analyze-string>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this transformation is applied on any XML document (not used) it processes the file: `c:\temp\delete\fileName.inc` which contains the provided text:

```
<li class="closed"><a title="x" href="x.html">x</a></li>
<li class="closed"><a title="y" href="y.html">y</a></li>
<li class="closed"><a title="z" href="a.html">z</a></li>
```

**and the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<value>x</value>
<value>y</value>
<value>z</value>
```

**And here is how to compare a variable to the extracted values:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vText" select=
      "unparsed-text('file:///c:/temp/delete/fileName.inc')"/>

    <xsl:param name="vSearchValue" select="'y'"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:variable name="vExtracted" as="element()*">
         <xsl:analyze-string select="$vText" regex="&gt;([^&lt;]*)&lt;/a&gt;" flags="m">
           <xsl:matching-substring>
             <value><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/></value>
           </xsl:matching-substring>
         </xsl:analyze-string>
     </xsl:variable>

     <xsl:sequence select="$vSearchValue = $vExtracted"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on any XML document (not used), the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
true
```

Comment: You always help with XSL problems. Can you also see this question that I posted today? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410876/float-image-in-pdf-using-xslfo Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 4):

With XSLT 2.0 you can use the `unparsed-text()` function to load the `nav.inc` file and then parse it with `xsl:analyze-string` to build a variable with a sequence of the `href` values:

```
<xsl:variable name="nav-links" as="item()*">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="unparsed-text('nav.inc')" regex="href=&quot;(.*)&quot;">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:sequence select="regex-group(1)"/>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:variable>
```